# Keycloak best way to add custom HTML

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I'm currently using Keycloak as an authentication provider, and I'm interested in incorporating custom themes. However, I'm facing a challenge regarding the inclusion of custom HTML. I would like to inquire about the best approach to achieve this.

Is it advisable to duplicate the base theme, insert my HTML content, and then place it in the providers folder? I have concerns about this method because I'd need to update the HTML code each time a new version with changes to the base theme is released. Therefore, I'd like to inquire if this is the recommended approach or if there's an alternative method that allows me to add custom HTML without modifying the base theme, while still keeping the base theme as the parent.

I appreciate your assistance!